# Changing properties svg from selector

Tags: jquery, svg

I have this svg and the polygon has the id 'uno'

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         width="1641px" height="820px" viewBox="0 0 1641 820" enable-background="new 0 0 1641 820" xml:space="preserve">
    <polygon id="uno" fill="#ff6600" fill-opacity="0" stroke="" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="350,228 579,102 603,240 713,292 722,343 744,354 650,433 
        651,482 633,496 592,477 541,516 473,465 462,420 399,383 358,236 "/>
```

I can change the properties if I do this

```
    $("#uno").on({mouseenter: function(){
    this.style.stroke = '#FF6600'; 
    this.style['stroke-width'] = 3;
    this.style['fill'] = '#ff6600';
    this.style['fill-opacity']=.5;
    } 
});
```

But why it does not work if I do this

```
  $('#uno').style.stroke = '#FF6600'; 
  $('#uno').style['stroke-width'] = 3;
  $('#uno').style['fill'] = '#ff6600';
  $('#uno').style['fill-opacity']=.5;
```

The objetive is to have a function when the selector is dynamic. For example.

```
$("#dos").on({mouseenter: function(){ animar(#uno);     } 
});

    function animar(a){
    a.style.stroke = '#FF6600'; 
    a.style['stroke-width'] = 3;
    a.style['fill'] = '#ff6600';
    a.style['fill-opacity']=.5;
}
```

Comment: There is not really a question in your question.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is the javascript object, while `$(this)` is jquery.

so doing this would work.

```
function animar(a){
    a.style.stroke = '#FF6600'; 
    a.style['stroke-width'] = 3;
    a.style['fill'] = '#ff6600';
    a.style['fill-opacity']=.5;
}

// if you can add clas
$(".js-svg-anmiate").on('mouseenter' function(){
      animar(this); 
});

// if you cant add class
$("#uni, #doit").on('mouseenter' function(){
      animar(this); 
});
```

Comment: Ok. But in the case where '#doit' is another button or different element and I want to animate '#uno'  `$("#doit").on({mouseenter: function(){ animar(#uno);     } });`